# Entity Framework Package Manager Console Commands Error - failed to build

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Whenever I try to run any entity framework command such as add-migration or update-database, the vast majority of the time I get an error "The project 'X' failed to build". The project builds fine in visual studio, and if I am persistent and keep trying eventually the command will work. It can be very frustrating as sometimes it will work on the first 5 tries, and sometimes it could take 50.

I have read around for tips and nothing has worked so far. I think it must be something to do with the settings that the package manager console uses to build the project but I don't know what they might be or how to configure them.

Has anyone run into this problem before that can offer advice?

Comment: Is there somehting on the Output window that can give you a clue?

Comment: No, and when I catch the error using -ErrorVariable , it points me to the line in the entity framework nugget that attempts to build the project and goes no deeper. So there is no useful message to tell me why the project failed to build.

Comment: which EF version areyou using?

Comment: Wait, the reference says 6.0.0.0 but in NugGet package manager it says 6.1.1 and there are no updates available.

Comment: Yes, the properties for the reference says Runtime Version: v4.0.30319 , and Version: 6.0.0.0 , and the path is C:\MySolutionDir\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll . So not sure why it says 6.0.0.0 in the properties window. I uninstalled the package, deleted my packages folder and re-installed. It still says the same.

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors after reinstalling the packages? What if you do a new dummy project from scratch? Does it work?

Comment: Still get the same problems on my original solution. I made a dummy with all my entity framework code dragged in and the package manager commands run first time. So it's a problem with my solution somewhere but I've got no error messages to hint what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this to be a problem caused by [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Suspending resharper whilst running the commands meant that they don't fail anymore. I can only assume the problem was resharper having a handle on files whilst the build script runs during the command executions.