# VS - My project doesnt want to build. 'Failed to build'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Yesterday one of my colleague sent to me example project which is created in VS. He told me I need to use something like 'NuGet'.
I have also 'Package Manager Console Host Version 3.4.4.1321'.

And when I'm trying to do something I have always this same error like:

```
PM> update-database
The project 'UserManagementApp' failed to build.
PM> Enable-Migrations
The project 'UserManagementApp' failed to build.
PM> update-database
The project 'UserManagementApp' failed to build.
PM> update-database
The project 'UserManagementApp' failed to build.
```

I cant write anything else. I tried also change 'Configuration' in Build->Configuration Manager and then change from 'Any CPU' to 'x86'. But this didnt resolve the issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you look at the **Output** tab in Visual Studio, what does it says? Any error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648526/entity-framework-package-manager-console-commands-error-failed-to-build 

Similar question, may help?

Comment: Resolved. Entity Framework version was 6.1.3, just unistalled and did 6.1.2. Now working.

Comment: @MariuszAdamczewski, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Would you please write your solution as the answer and mark it? So it would be helpful for other members who meet the same issue as yours. Have a nice day:)